# What do I understand from Person(String)?

Tags: java, string, methods, abstract

[image]

Hello friends,
I am new to code. Please help me with this image. I understand most of things in the image except "Person(String)". What is it? 
 thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the image since the class name and the method name as same. It is called as constructor. So if written in code it should look like this

```
public abstract class Person
{
    public Person(String name)
    {

    }
}
```

Since the class is abstract this cannot be instantiated . It should done from the derived class.